# Обработка событий с RadioButton

Tags: jquery, ajax

Есть три кнопки:

```
<input type="radio" name="visible" value="1" class="checkbox_visible"/><b>View</b><br />
<input type="radio" name="visible" value="2" class="checkbox_visible"/><b>In work</b><br />
<input type="radio" name="visible" value="3" class="checkbox_visible"/><b>Done</b>
```

Как сделать так, что бы при выборе одной из кнопки отправлялся `ajax` запрос `value` выбранной кнопки?

Comment: $('input[type=radio][name=visible]:selected').val()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Селектор если меняется, то можете заменить на другой:

```
$(document).on('click', '.checkbox_visible', function() {
    var value = $(this).val();

    $.ajax({
        url: '/path/to/file',
        data: {value: value},
    })
    .done(function() {
        console.log("success");
    })
    .fail(function() {
        console.log("error");
    })
    .always(function() {
        console.log("complete");
    });
});
```